# Jquery copy from one field to another if not empty

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

I have the below code which is working fine for me. The only problem is that the keyup function I would like to work only if #input-custom-field12 is not empty.

So an example.

If #input-custom-field = something then copy the value. **(like i am doing and working)**

If #input-custom-field = empty do nothing**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $( "#input-custom-field12" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#value2" ).text( value );
  })
  .keyup();
});

</script>

<form id="viewtrades" name="myform2" action=".." target="_blank" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"> User ID 
<select name="userid">
  <option id="value1">3005862</option>
  <option id="value2"></option>
</select>

    <br>
```

Comment: `if(value!=="")` you are just missing one if condition

Comment: can you give me an example. I am very beginner on jquery. My level is unfortunately 0-1 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $( "#input-custom-field12" ).keyup(function() {
        if ($( this ).val()) {
            $( "#value2" ).text( $( this ).val() );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20867329)

Answer (score 0):

You should use val instead of text, input type text has to be served with val.

I think you really don't need any blank check, Take a look at this.

```js
$("#input-custom-field12").keyup(function() {    
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    $("#userid option").each(function() {
      if($(this).text().trim() == value.trim()) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
      }                        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-custom-field12" />
<form id="viewtrades" name="myform2" action="....." target="_blank" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"> User ID <select id="userid" name="userid"><option id="value2"></option> <option id="value1">3005862</option>  </select> <br> </form>
```

Comment: i don't have input id = "value2" . it's select box. It's not working like this. maybe any change?

Comment: Post your html please

Comment: <form id="viewtrades" name="myform2" action="....." target="_blank" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"> User ID 
<select name="userid">
  <option id="value1">3005862</option>
  <option id="value2"></option>
</select>
 
    <br>
                <input id="dateform" class="mybuttonresults inputcidaccountform" type="submit" value="View All Trades"> <br>  </form>

Comment: You mean if the value is in select then it should be selected other wise not right?

Comment: If value of the input = 0 do nothing. If value of input < 1 then the keyup to work

Comment: You can adjust your condition accordingly, Please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-custom-field12").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val().trim();
            if (value != undefined && value != null && value != "") {
                $("#value2").val(value);
            }
        });
    });
```